# Can I install pytorch on nvidia jetson tx1?

Tags: installation, deep-learning, nvidia, pytorch

Because Tensorflow does not support ARM chips, I would like to install pytorch on Jetson TX1 to do some experiments. But I have not found any related resources about building pytorch into Jetson TX, is this possible?

Comment: what difference does it make which chip it has, it has CUDA, so that's what TF will be using. (as far as I know, not really an expert yet - http://www.nvidia.com/object/jetson-tx1-module.html )

Comment: Of course TensorFlow runs in ARM chips: https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi

Comment: Yes, thank you! After a bit of searching, I found someone has already built tensorflow onto Jetson TX1. The link is here: https://github.com/jetsonhacks/installTensorFlowTX1/